# How can I fix the error argument of type Boolean or undefined using React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting an error,

> Argument of type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of 'type boolean'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

when I am passing a prop from a child to a usehook like below.

Below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    const [isDialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <DialogComponent isDialogOpen={isDialogOpen}                     setDailogOpen={setDialogOpen}/>
         </Wrapper>
    );
}

interface ChildComponentProps {
    isDialogOpen: boolean,
    setIsDialogOpen: any,
}

function ChildComponent ({isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen} : ChildComponentProps) {
    const count = 10;
    useSomehook(isDialogOpen, count); // Error here
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <div>somedivs</div>
            {isDialogOpen && <Overlay/>}
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

I have useSomehook defined in the other file like below,

```
export function useSomehook(enabled: boolean, count:number) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (enabled) {
            trigger(count);
        }
    }, [enabled, count, trigger]);
}
```

I am new to using TypeScript. How can I fix this error?

Comment: `useSomehook(enabled: boolean | undefined, count:number)` should fix it

Comment: The reason why you get ```undefined``` in ```isDialogOpen``` is usage of ```React.useState(false)``` instead of ```React.useState<boolean>(false)```. Try to define generic type explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a useState using a Boolean. In TypeScript you have to be sure that whatever variable you pass as a Boolean in this case can't be undefined.

There are multiple solutions, but a quick fix would be to fix your component like this.

```
function ChildComponent ({isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen} : ChildComponentProps) {
    const count= 10;
    useSomehook(isDialogOpen !== undefined ? isDialogOpen : false, count); //error here
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <div>somedivs</div>
            {isDialogOpen && <Overlay/>}
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

This makes sure that if isDialogOpen is not undefined, we will use that value, otherwise we use the Boolean "false". You can edit this to your liking, of course.